# Am I doing anything wrong here - when trying to visualize the wordcloud with matplotlib?

Tags: python, word-cloud, wordcloud2

This is my first project on word cloud - can any please help to solve the issue ? I'm getting an error - Type Error: 'module' object is not callable. Here is the below complete code for your reference.

```
# necessary library import
from wordcloud import wordcloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

#my text
data = '''Data science is the field of study that combines domain expertise, programming skills, and knowledge of mathematics and statistics to extract meaningful insights from data. Data science practitioners apply machine learning algorithms to numbers, text, images, video, audio, and more to produce artificial intelligence (AI) systems to perform tasks that ordinarily require human intelligence. In turn, these systems generate insights which analysts and business users can translate into tangible business value.'''

#funtion for word tokenize and remove stopwords
def data_processing(data):
    data_tokens = word_tokenize(data)
    
    processed_words = [w for w in data_tokens if not w in stop_words]
    return " ".join(processed_words)

#function run 
data_processed = data_processing(data)

#wordcloud visualization
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), facecolor = 'none')
wordcloud= wordcloud().generate(data)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In the API it seems it should be `from wordcloud import WordCloud`, and the constructor is `WordCloud()`. Capitalization is important. Also, don't try to shadow the module name as a variable. Instead, call the variable something like `wc`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Thank you very much for your kind support .  I have called the variable with wc and  from wordcloud import WordCloud.

my problem has been solved!!

Comment: Next time you get an error like `'module' object is not callable`, just remember that a module is a file containing code, and you call functions _from_ the module. This error means that Python tries to call the module, so somewhere in your code is either a direct wrong call (e.g. `import numpy as np` - `foo = np()`), or you've created an ambiguous alias such as in this case :)

Comment: Understood!! I did a mistake while calling wordCloud () without any alias.  and also actual module is wordCloud not wordcloud (C should be caps)

Thanks for your all valuable suggestion!! your quick help & the suggestion means me lot.

Comment: I'm actually having to double down on what I said, because in this instance you used `from wordcloud import wordcloud`, and I don't understand how that didn't give an error since wordcloud's `__init__` doesn't contain a valid import for `wordcloud`. What I said does hold though, but in this case I'm confused as to why the import _did_ work and the error only happens once you call the module. I guess if Jupyter runs on Windows (which I doubt), it would make sense that it's not case sensitive. Really perculiar.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal my account got blocked in stack overflow - Can you please share your linkdin profile ? I would like connect with you.